# How to solve complex-valued , inhomogeneous second order differential equations?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I am trying to find a general method to solve the following complex-valued ,  inhomogeneous  second order differential equation
$$ -a(x) u''(x)+b(x)u'(x)+c(x)u(x)+d(x)\bar{u}(x)=f(x),\quad x\in\mathbb{R}\tag{C-ODE}\label{ode}$$
where $a,$ $d,$ $c,$ $d$ are complex-valued functions.

As far as I know, if $d\equiv 0$ and if one knew a special solution to \eqref{ode} with $f\equiv 0,$ one can find general solutions to \eqref{ode}  by using Wronskian and formula of variation of parameters.

However, I have no idea how to solve \eqref{ode} if $d\not\equiv 0.$ Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: I take it $\overline{u}$ is the complex conjugate? 

I imagine you could separate the real and imaginary parts and get a system of real DEs.

Comment: @Paul Wright, yes, $\bar{u}$ means the complex conjugate of $u.$ However, since the funtions in the coefficients are complex valued, if I seperate the real and imaginary parts respectively, then I will get a system of linear coupled differential equations with each other.

Comment: From there you could use a substitution to either convert to a 4th order DE with one function, or a 1st order DE with four functions. Then you can use Wronskians and variation of parameters again, or possibly matrix exponentials.

Comment: @PaulWright,thank you. Following your suggestion, I've  converted (C-ODE) to a  1st order system with four components. It worked.